# Xamarin Studio generate CSS from SASS or LESS files

Tags: css, sass, less, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm building a OWIN based Web-Application with Xamarin Studio on MacOS X. 
How can I configure Xamarin Studio to build the CSS files from the LESS sources?

Comment: There is no other solution than to write a script: [link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33703/is-there-sass-or-less-support-in-xamarin-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution to this myself.  What I do now is I setup Grunt to do the compilation of the SASS files and run it in a command prompt.